# Loop through a table and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table. I'm trying to get my script, loop through the table, to find if there is any content in the td's and `.hide()` my button if there is or `.show()` if there isn't.

DEMO: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcdk1eh8/1/)

Then on clicking the button, loop through all the td's and add a class to them.

```
// <!-- Whether or not to display the button depending if there is anything in each td -->
function Example(column) {
    var rows = $("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log('>><<>><<>><<>><<', column)
        if ($(rows[i]).find("td" [column]).find(".unavailable").length > 0) {
            $('.button-fill').hide();
        } else {
            $('.button-fill').show();
        }
    }
};

// <!-- Fill in the td -->
function bookAllDay() {
    $('.button-fill').click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            $(rows[i]).find("td" [column]).addClass("active");
        }
    });
};
for (var i = 5 - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    Example(i);
};
```

I've added a really, stripped down version of my table and code in jsfiddle. So some things may be missing from the example I've drawn from my work but I've tried my best.

Thanks!

Comment: [Don't use jQuery's hide/show](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88#issuecomment-72400007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate over all tr's and td's and `:empty`selector can be used to check if any element is empty or not. Try the following working code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.button-fill').on("click", function() { 
        var i=$(this).parent().index();

       if($(this).closest("tr").siblings().find("td:eq("+i+")").text()=="")
           $(this).hide();
       else
           $(this).show();    
    });

<!-- Fill in the td -->
    $('.button-fill').on("click", function() {
      var i=$(this).parent().index();
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().find("td:eq("+i+")").addClass("active");
      //});
  });
});
```

[DEMO UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/vcdk1eh8/6/)

Comment: Thank you, the issue is. The button (even though I left it out in the jsfiddle) is in the column. So there are four columns with four buttons. I want to display and hide the button and add the class `'active'` on only the td elements in that column

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy So each cell has its own button and on click of a button only that particular cell will have red color and active class??

Comment: I just updated the jsfiddle so it's more like this http://jsfiddle.net/vcdk1eh8/4/ so each button will display depending on whether the td elements in the column have anything in. And highlight all the elements in that row `onClick`

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy Check the updated code and fiddle now .. is it fine now?

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop through table. You can use the [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) pseudo-selector to select all the `td` having no content.

> **:empty**: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

**Code:**

```
// Check if there are empty td's
if ($('table').find('td:empty').length) {
    // Show the button, if there is at least one empty td
    $('.button-fill').show();
} else {
    $('.button-fill').hide();
}
```

You can also use `toggle` to make the code short.

```
$('.button-fill').toggle($('table').find('td:empty').length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
var row = $(rows[i]);

if (row.find("td"[column]).find(".unavailable").length > 0) {
  row.find('.button-fill').addClass("hide");
} else {
  row.find('.button-fill').removeClass("hide");
}
```

You're selecting every button on the page with a matching class currently.

Comment: Use CSS to show/hide elements not jquery (at least look into using something else).